# Returning the String at the index typed in by the user (ArrayList)

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create a simple method. Basically, I want this method (called "returnIndex") to return the word at the ArrayList index number the user types in.

Example:
If the user types in "1", is should return whatever String is at index 1 in the ArrayList.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void returnIndex ()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in)
    while (in.hasNextLine())
    {
        if (in.equals(1))
        {
            //return item at that index
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure how to say "return the item at that index" in Java. Of course, I'll have to make the code work with any other number, not just '1'. But for now, I'm focusing on '1'. Not even sure if the `in.equals(1)` part is even 100% right.

My apologies if this question seems a little elementary. I'm still working on my Java. Just hints please, no complete answers. Thank you very much.

Comment: Where's the ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

```
public String returnIndex(Scanner in, List<String> list) {
    return list.get(in.nextInt());
}
```

- Don't create new Scanners as it can cause subtle problems. Instead, create only one and keep using it. That means you should pass it into this function.
- There's no need to use ArrayList when List will do (as it will here).
- You need to make the function return `String`, not `void`, if you want it to return a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        values.add("One");
        values.add("Two");
        values.add("Three");

        String result = getStringAtIndex(values);
        System.out.println("The result:" + result);

    }

    public static String getStringAtIndex(List<String> list) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int index = 0;
        index = scanner.nextInt();
        return list.get(index-1);
    }
```